# Css word wrap with style

Tags: html, css

i want to show second line of wrap text with space .

OUTPUT:

```
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
     industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
     since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
```

my code:

```
<style>p{
 overflow:word-wrap;
}</style>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty easy to handle.  The trick is to add a little padding, and then actually "indent" the first line with a negative value.  Sort of thinking outside the box.

```css
p {
    padding-left: 2em;
    text-indent:-2em;
}
```

```html
<p>
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text 
 ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
</p>
```